# Jupyter config python file with py underscore extension

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I was reading through https://dataschool.com/data-modeling-101/running-jupyter-notebook-on-an-ec2-server/ and I happened to notice one of the steps involves editing a configuration file named `vim jupyter_notebook_config.py_`. At first, I thought the underscore at the end was a typo; further testing revealed editing this file does have the intended effect.

I don't see this documented in Jupyter's official documentation. Does anyone know if reading `jupyter_notebook_config.py_` (with underscore) is an undocumented feature?

P.S. I did some brief digging in https://github.com/jupyter/notebook, but could not find an answer.